# Multiple simultaneous requests to same host for same task give "Data could not be sent to remote host IP. Make sure this host can be reached over ssh

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

### Scenario

I run the following tasks in two terminals at the same time

- first one succeeds
- second one gives above error

So we are getting the above error while running the ansible-playbook for multiple sessions at the same time

> Data could not be sent to remote host [internal ip]. Make sure this host can be reached over ssh

The piece of code being executed by task which fails is

```yaml
- name: run docker container
  docker_container:
    name: "{{ container_name }}"
    image: "organization/{{ app_name }}:{{ docker_image_version }}"
#    command: "{{ adhoc_command }}"
    command: "/bin/sh /data/run-command.sh"
    state: started
    recreate: yes
    capabilities:
      - sys_time
    cap_drop:
      - all
    privileged: true
    cleanup: true
    detach: false
    network_mode: host
    env_file: "{{ adhock_data_path }}/{{ app_name }}/{{ md5suffix }}/.env"
    volumes:
      - "{{ adhock_data_path }}/{{ app_name }}/{{ md5suffix }}:/data:rw"
```

I suspect it is happening as we are trying to do some heavy tasks in the container at the same time.
I was thinking if there was some solution to delay the connection as well with something like the following

```yaml
  wait_for_connection:
    delay: 30
    timeout: 300
```

But we have the same issue when both the tasks are being executed simultaneously. Any help would be appreciated.

If required, I can provide additional information as well.

Comment: I suspect this is more based on `recreate: yes` that actively restart your container, and thus, create a downtime where the container cannot be reached.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε, thanks a lot but the container names are different for different simultaneous executions of ansible-playbook so this should not impact. Agree ? The containers names are actually base64 encoded with runtime params passed to the playbook

Comment: Oh, so it is to the same host but not the same container, right? Didn't grasp that from your question.

Comment: yes @β.εηοιτ.βε exactly. Yeah i figured so i edited the question for more information. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your ansible.cfg with the value `retries = 5` which will allow your playbook to retry connecting to the host 5 times with retry delay of 1s, 2s, 4s and etc. This will be more explanatory on your `ansible.cfg` file itself. Check once.